# Serialize an ISO 8601 time/duration "Thhmmss-hhmm/PTmm" ie ("T063000-0600/PT10M") to a rust struct

Tags: rust, serialization, iso8601, serde

I'm writing a fairly simple REST api, one of my objects will want to know a time of day and duration to be activated. I'm hoping I can serialize an ISO 8601 Time/Duration into a data members of a struct in rust using actix-web, serde and chrono, is this possible?

I've done some initial research into serde serilization and chrono, but I'm not finding much other than very basic datetime serialization. Not quite what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything is possible, of course, but in this case you will have to do some of the lifting yourself or using another crate, because chrono's `Duration` type doesn't provide formatting or parsing utilities.

You can implement the time half quite easily.  Note that chrono doesn't have a "time with timezone" type, so I will use `NaiveTime` and assume UTC.

```
use chrono::{NaiveTime, Duration};
use serde::Serialize;

struct TimeWithDuration {
    pub time: NaiveTime,
    pub duration: Duration,
}

impl Serialize for TimeWithDuration {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: serde::Serializer,
    {
        serializer.serialize_str(&format!(
            "{}/{}",
            self.time.format("T%H%M%SZ"),
            format_duration(self.duration),
        )
    }
}

fn format_duration(duration: Duration) -> impl Display {
    todo!()
}
```

`format_duration` is a placeholder function that should format the duration appropriately.  You might consider looking into the [iso8601-duration crate](https://docs.rs/iso8601-duration/latest/iso8601_duration/).

Comment: Me not knowing the difference between the annotation and implementing Serialize...
If there are more fields do I need to also implement Serialize for each field ie struct looks like
`#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct MoistureSensor {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub name: String,
    pub description: String,
    pub power_pin: i32,
    pub analog_pin: i32,
    pub start_time: NaiveTime,
    pub duration: Duration,
}`

Comment: @JeremyJones You would combine `start_time` and `duration` into a single struct like I have in my answer, assuming that the value is provided in a single string value in the input. For example if you have JSON like `{ "time_duration": "T063000-0600/PT10M" }` then you would have `#[derive(Serialize)] struct MoistureSensor { pub time_duration: TimeWithDuration }`.